# Как вывести массив из unicode строк?

Tags: python, django

Питон ведет себя следующим образом:

```
>>> mass = (u'Привет', u'Пока')
>>> mass[0]
u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442'
>>> print mass[0]
Привет
```

но

```
>>> mass
(u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442', u'\u041f\u043e\u043a\u0430')
>>> print mass
(u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442', u'\u041f\u043e\u043a\u0430')
```

Как вывести такой массив в читабельном виде?

Как решить тот же вопрос в django? Нужно выполнить

```
return render_to_response('mass_page.html', {'mass': mass})
```

Этот вывод ведет себя также как `print`: один элемент выводит читабельным, массив - нет. Просто циклом, я думаю, здесь не обойтись.

Comment: Ну все верно, как раз циклом элементы массива выводятся в читабельном виде.

Comment: А в django? Создавать много переменных и туда циклом выводить?

Comment: почему много? {% for item in mass %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}

Comment: спасибо за совет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поиграться с это строкой, и поймете

> HttpResponse(json.dumps(placemarks, ensure_ascii=False),
>   content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8;")